# Manually set tag to Azure Release pipeline Tags

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to add tag to Tags column in Azure Release pipelines? I would like to set it during the pipeline run, so each run will have different tag. I can rename release name(#vso[release.updatereleasename]...), but is there something for tag?

screen from azure release pipelines

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add tag for release in release pipleine, you can use below rest api:
[image]

In release pipeline, you can add `powershell` task with inline content as below:

```
 $personalToken = "$(personalToken)"
 $token =   [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
 $header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
 $Uri = "$(System.TeamFoundationServerUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/Release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)/tags/$(yourtag)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
 Write-Host $Uri
 Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $Uri -Headers $header
```

Please define variable `personalToken` and `yourtag` in variable list.

The task result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and help. One more question, why dont you use system_accesstoken in your script? 
-Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

Comment: Glad to know it works! Good point, System accesstoken is also working. You can use it or PAT. Thanks